# Security on this script

Tags: php, mysql, security, session, authentication

I've been building a login script now lately, and I would need some suggestions on security. Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'inc/conn.php';
include 'inc/config.php';
include 'inc/session.php'; //Prevent session hijack

if (isset($_SESSION['banned'])) {
    header("Location: banned.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (isset($_SESSION['token']) 
        && $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {

        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);       
        $_POST['password'] = sha1($salt1 . $_POST['password'] . $salt2);

        $user_query = "SELECT id, userlevel FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "' AND password = '" . $_POST['password'] . "'";
        $user_result = mysql_query($user_query);

        if (mysql_num_rows($user_result) == 0) {
            $error = 'Fel användarnamn eller lösenord';
        } else {

            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_result);

            $banned_query = "SELECT * FROM bans WHERE user_id = " . $row['id'] . "";
            $banned_result = mysql_query($banned_query);

            session_regenerate_id();

            if (mysql_num_rows($banned_result) == 0) {

                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row['userlevel'];

                header("Location: index.php");
                exit;

            } else {

                $ban_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($banned_result);

                $_SESSION['banned'] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $ban_row['user_id'];

                header("Location: banned.php");
                exit;

            }
        }
    }

}

$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;

?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
?>
<?php if (isset($error)) echo $error ?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
Användarnamn<br />
<input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
Lösenord<br />
<input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Logga in" />
</form>
<?php } else { echo var_dump($_SESSION); } ?>
```

config.php and conn is just two files, one with database connection, other with two static variables.

session.php

```
<?php
$string = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$string .= 'SHIFLETT';

$fingerprint = md5($string);

if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) &&
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != $fingerprint) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
    exit;
} else {
  $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = $fingerprint;
}
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where $salt1 and $salt2 defined?

Comment: Salt needs to be different per user account not the same for all users. So that's a fail. Also SHA1 is broken use sha2 instead. Finally theres no need to salt a value twice. One salt at the start ! is all you need.

Comment: [How To Safely Store A Password](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) (short summary: use bcrypt, not sha/md5)

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the `mysqli_xxx` functions rather than the `mysql_xxx` functions.

See the PHP manual for an [overview of the mysqli extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) and how it differs from the older mysql extension.

Using the mysqli functions will allow you to use features such as prepared statements, which makes it much easier to write secure code.

As a basic level, it's a fairly trivial set of changes to move to the mysqli library. The changes to start using prepared statements, etc may be slightly more work, but well worth it.

The only reason to still be using the older mysql functions is if you're stuck on an ancient version of MySQL. But if that's the case, you likely have plenty of other security issues to worry about anyway.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the information you have provided so far, you script seems to be protected against SQL Injections. And that’s it.

Your “Session Hijacking prevention” is rather only an attempt to mitigate the probability but doesn’t prevent it. Because Session Hijacking attacks most often use techniques to obtain a victim’s session ID that can also unveil the victim’s user agent ID (like [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) or checking the HTTP referrer).

To be honest, preventing Session Hijacking is quite difficult. But there are attempts like the one described in [SessionSafe: Implementing XSS Immune Session Handling](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/SVS/papers/2006_esorics_SessionSafe.pdf).

Comment: I use HTMLPurifier as for XSS Protection. I have set in my php.ini configuration file, stuff like you can't index.php?sessid=123. And seriously, I get really paronoid, as I want to keep my applications secure.

Answer (score 0):

looks fine bro, I would do

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['submit']=='submit')
```